# How deleted at working with laravel with different foreign key

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, cascading-deletes

Here is my code :

I have created a table that is `image_upload`. In this table there are 2 colou that is `post_id`,`post_name`, `deleted_at`, `created_at`, `updated_at`. Post id belong to post table.

When user deletes a post, I am trying to use soft delete in laravel and update the `deleted_at` in image_upload table. I have added below code in my model

**POST MODEL :**

```
public function imageLinks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ImageUpload::class, 'post_id'); 
    }
```

When I delete a post, I get this error. My column name is `post_id` but it will take `id`. I don't understand what exact issue.

> "message": "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: update `image_upload` set `deleted_at` = 2020-07-03 21:28:14, `updated_at` = 2020-07-03 21:28:14 where `id` is null)",

Comment: Which part of the code executes this SQL query ?

Comment: @anouares-sayid, I have write this code on my Post Model for my ImageUpdate Model

Comment: I just want when some one deleted the post, in my image upload table deleted at will be add date.

Comment: post the controller where you invoke the `where` method

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you add this couple lines on your Delete_post() function :
For example

```
$post=post::where('id',=,$id)->get(); 
$post->delete();
  
//And you can 

$images=imageUpload::where('post_id',=,$post['id'])->delete();

//Or 

$post->imageLinks()->delete();
```

But I don't understand why you have added post_name in the images table that doesn't make sense because you can get it using relationships .